# Fetching JSON not working in site but working in localhost

Tags: javascript, html, json, database, fetch-api

Json fetching has worked before in site for example here where i used the same processes - https://n-ce.github.io/Sea-arch

Here's the script

```
//FETCH
function content(a){
fetch(a+'.json').then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
      appendData(data);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
    });
}

//Loading the objects
var root = document.getElementById('root');
function appendData(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = data[i].Name;
    root.appendChild(p);
  } 
}


// Remove Function

function remove(){
  while (root.hasChildNodes()) {
    root.removeChild(root.firstChild);
  }
}

// Click decision making

var count = couns = 0;

function Sites() {
  if(count%2==0){
    content('Sites');
    count++;
  }
  else{
    count--;
    remove();
  }
}
function Animals() {
  if (couns % 2 == 0) {
    content('Animals');
    couns++;
  }
  else {
    couns--;
    remove();
  }
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JSON SD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body onload="content('Onload')">
    <span>
      <button onclick="Animals()">Load Animals</button>
      <button onclick="Sites()">Load Sites</button>
    </span>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is no way for me to debug this given that the console doesnot throw any errors since its working fine in localhost.
Im fairly new to the Fetch API But
Im thinking maybe  it is because the json files are  being transferred are taking too long?
Can someone please highlight whats the issue?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not just as links to a repository (which will likely be updated when you find the solution).

Comment: You can't just dump a link to a whole repo and "Deal with it guys, I'll wait". You want us to clone your repo, go through all your code, reproduce the issue without any more instruction, debug your app, find the culprit, and provide a fix? No thanks :)

Comment: [not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem.

Comment: Sorry guys, im fairly new to s.o., i have update the question since to incorporate more details about the issue.

Comment: I think it is having a different result because your link on github isn't `/`, It's `/Sea-arch`. This explains why `fetch('Animals.json')` doesn't work. It should be `fetch('./Animals.json')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it worked for github pages, thanks to @programmarRaj for highlighting
Script

```
//FETCH
function content(a){
fetch("./"+a+".json").then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
      appendData(data);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
    });
}
```